# In netbeans how to compile the C++ project on another computer with different architecture

Tags: c++, netbeans, architecture

I've created a netbeans C++ project on x86 ubuntu machine and then copied the project to BeagleBoneBlack(BBB) armhf computer. I added BBB to C/C++ build hosts and opened the project. Now when I build It through netbeans, the build fails with "Failed to get process PID". How to change the project architecture from x86 to armhf?